# Node JS / Socket.io : include JS lib in HTML

Tags: node.js, socket.io

That's surely a noob question, but the thing is : **how can I easily include JS libs to the front-end part of a Node (with Socket.io) app ?**

What I did in my HTML file :

```
<script src="libs/hammer.js"></script>
```

This HTML file is handled by Node :

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){  
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

So, as expected, the client can't find `http://127.0.0.1:3000/libs/hammer.js` (assuming I'm running locally on port 3000) : it returns a 404 on that request.

**Should I handle those libs with node_modules ? or something else ?**  I'm pretty lost on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using express, you need to serve them with `express.static`.

Add this to your middleware stack:

```
app.use('/libs', express.static(__dirname + '/libs'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally miss that point. I'll check Express doc about that. That's working fine right now :)